# Update toggle switch state in android UI according to firebase data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I've recently started working on android and firebase. I'm trying to develop an application for IOT where the application should get the state of the switch(1 or 0) from the firebase and update toggle switch state. [This is the firebase json data. I need to update toggle switches based on the values of LR1, LR2, LR3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1whk.png)

I've tried attaching `ValueEventListener` to toggle switches and Overriding `onDataChange()`, `onDataCancelled()` methods in `onSavedInstanceState`(Bundle savedInstanceState), `onStart()`. As soon as I kill the app and launch again, all the switches are displaying default(OFF) state. I need the UI to get updated with the current values every time it is launched and should change even when the app is in foreground. Please help me with it. Thank you in advance!!

[This is onCreate() method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t273G.jpg) [This is onStart() method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajt4E.jpg) [This is SwitchStatus Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBFmy.jpg)

Comment: show your codes where you get the firebase values. you might have retrieved the data before the views are ready, and failed to update it manually after onCreate. you probably want  to use addListenerForSingleValueEvent somewhere in your onCreate method

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: I've added the codes. Please go through them and suggest any changes. Thank you!!

Comment: @rajeevmukhesh please see the answer and mark it correct if that is what you were looking for

Comment: The defaults states could be set in your .xml file android:checked="true" which is always setting it to true on load

Answer (score 0):

Declare your widget

```
private Switch sNotificationIndividualChat;
private DatabaseReference fbDbRefRoot;
```

In onCreate bind it

```
sNotificationIndividualChat = findViewById(R.id.a_my_profile_settings_s_notification_individual_chat);
fbDbRefRoot = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Then Declare your Model Class

```
public class MyProfileSettingsModel {

    private String notification_individual_chat;

    public MyProfileSettingsModel() {
    }

    public MyProfileSettingsModel(String notification_individual_chat) {
        this.notification_individual_chat = notification_individual_chat;
    }

    public String getNotification_individual_chat() {
        return notification_individual_chat;
    }

    public void setNotification_individual_chat(String notification_individual_chat) {
        this.notification_individual_chat = notification_individual_chat;
    }
}
```

Then get values from firebase and update accordingly.  Use your own references

```
fbDbRefRoot.child("user_profile_settings").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        // Use The Model Class To Get The Data
        final MyProfileSettingsModel myProfileSettingsModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(MyProfileSettingsModel.class);

        String notificationIndividualChat = myProfileSettingsModel.getNotification_individual_chat();

        if (notificationIndividualChat.equals("0")) {
            sNotificationIndividualChat.setChecked(true);

            sNotificationIndividualChat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    fbDbRefRoot.child("user_profile_settings").child(current_user_id)
                            .child("notification_individual_chat").setValue("1");

                }
            });
        }
        if (notificationIndividualChat.equals("1")) {
            sNotificationIndividualChat.setChecked(false);

            sNotificationIndividualChat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    fbDbRefRoot.child("user_profile_settings").child(current_user_id)
                            .child("notification_individual_chat").setValue("0");

                }
            });
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: You can probably use boolean for your switch states but please don't downvote because of that, also not exactly your values but I think this is what you were asking for.